# Google wont read my robots.txt on s3

Tags: amazon-s3, web-crawler, robots.txt, googlebot

As google is crawling our static content (stored on s3) we created a robots.txt in root directory (of the bucket).. as following

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Now since we wanted to remove exisiting content from google search .. we added the bucket in google webmaster a/c .. And requested for directory removal

Now the issue is that google wont recognize or read the robots.txt (which is need to future blocking of google block).. We r getting this message in webmaster tools

---

**This site is not located at the top level for the domain. 
A robots.txt file is only valid when located in the highest-level directory and applies to all directories within the domain. 
The robots.txt file that applies to your site (if one exists) is located at http://s3.amazonaws.com/robots.txt. This page provides information on that file.**

Comment: How did you determine it's actually google? Are you sure it's somebody impersonating the google bot? P.S. I can't access your robots.txt file: I get an access denied error. Are you sure it's accessible to google too?

Answer (score 11):

Which URL did you give Google for your bucket? You need to use the *DNS-style* `{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com`, instead of the *path-style* `s3.amazonaws.com/{bucket}`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. Have changed my s3 files path from s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/ to bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com .. Now google recognized my robots.txt

Comment: Don't forget that Google will still spider your files if you have links on your site of the form: s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/SOMEFILE - you need to change everything to use the {bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/SOMEFILE links everywhere for the robots.txt to have the desired effect.

Answer (score -1):

I get an access denied error when I try to look at your robots.txt, are you sure that Google can see your robots file?

In addition, you can [check your robots.txt at Google](http://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/20/check-your-robotstxt-at-google/) in real time and confirm exactly what Google is seeing when they take a look at your robots.txt (if they can even see it).

Comment: Wondering how you got the link to my robots.txt.. anyways issue is resolved now on using DNS style bucket url as suggested by @Ryan

Comment: My robots.txt was located at http://s3.amazonaws.com/[mybuckname]/Robots.txt but google only accepts robots.txt located in the root folder http://s3.amazonaws.com/Robots.txt.. which i had not control.